# How to install conan inside docker and use

Tags: docker, cmake, conan

I am trying to use Conan by installing it in a Docker and using that docker. For the same, I did like
included these lines in Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN sudo python3 -m pip install conan
```

And after starting docker container I have these lines in my CMakeFile.txt

```
conan_cmake_run(
    REQUIRES
    ${CONAN_PACKAGES})
```

The `${CONAN_PACKAGES}` is required to build my project. While running the cmakefile I'm getting this error

```
-- Conan: Automatic detection of conan settings from cmake
-- Conan: Settings= -s;build_type=Debug;-s;compiler=gcc;-s;compiler.version=8;-s;compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
-- Conan: checking conan executable
-- Conan: Found program /usr/bin/conan
-- Conan: Version found 
-- Conan executing: /usr/bin/conan install . -s build_type=Debug -s compiler=gcc -s compiler.version=8 -s compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 -g=cmake
CMake Error at cmake/conan.cmake:402 (message):
  Conan install failed='No such file or directory'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/conan.cmake:497 (conan_cmake_install)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (conan_cmake_run)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Addition of conan_remote is working fine.
But after creating the docker container executing these line inside docker fixed the problem

```
pip install conan
sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/conan /usr/bin/conan
```

With my initial understanding of conan, I realized that it is looking for user level installation. But in docker everything is installed as root.
Can someone please help to fix this?
I'm using this version of conan: https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/tree/release/0.15

Comment: I would suggest you using the official Conan docker images: https://hub.docker.com/u/conanio. They are available by compiler version, for instance, `conanio/gcc10`. The repository is this one, if you want to take a look on recipes: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools
BTW, do not use root user as default, instead, create a non-root user. Why? Security flaw, all applications will run as root, including possible malwares.

Comment: @uilianries Thanks for your suggestion. But there is a restriction to consume the existing Dockerfiles and add packages to the same if required. And we are creating a user in the docker as well.

Comment: So I would suggest you reading the Dockerfile in Github as example. Use pyenv for python install, so you can keep a specific version installed, not depending what is available from your distribution. Another point, first you used python3 -m pip install, but after you just executed pip install. I'm not sure if they are the same pip, the second command could be python 2.7. I suggest you using pip3 just in case, and check with pip --version just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the dockerfile
instead of

```
RUN sudo python3 -m pip install conan
```

try this:

```
RUN pip install conan
```

Comment: This fails at least using Kaniko: "This environment is externally managed [...] If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package, create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv [...]"